# When is a creature a Target?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

For a [Fleecemane Lion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFleecemane%20Lion%5d) when you pay and place a +1/+1 on it making it monstrous.  Is the counter targeting Fleecemane Lion.  If someone casts an effect or activates an ability to change the target does this mean Fleecemane Lion is not monstrous?

Comment: Specifically, sub-question 2 deals with monstrosity.

Comment: Best rule of thumb here. Does the ability say the word "target" if not, then there's no targeting involved (there are exceptions, like auras, but in general this applies.

Comment: 3 things target: 1) Spells/abilities that use the word target, 2) Keyword abilities that represent abilities that use the word target, and 3) Auras on the stack.

Comment: When that creature is a minotaur (joking, see [Target Minotaur](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=target%20minotaur))